# How to fix error message "The converter failed to save the file" after creating excel using OpenXml

Tags: vb.net, openxml

I created an excel file using OpenXML. But when I try to open the created xlsx, this error message was displayed.
"The converter failed to save the file"

I already installed this "FileFormatConverters.exe"

Here is my code:
Using sp As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create("C:\OpenXML.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)
            Dim wBookPart As WorkbookPart = sp.AddWorkbookPart

```
        Dim wBook As Workbook = New Workbook

        Dim sheet As Sheet = New Sheet
        Dim sheets As Sheets = New Sheets

        sheet.Name = "TestSheet"
        sheet.Id = "r1d1"
        sheets.Append(sheet)

        wBook.Append(sheets)
        wBookPart.Workbook = wBook

        Dim wSheetPart As WorksheetPart
        wSheetPart = wBookPart.AddNewPart(Of WorksheetPart)("r1d1")

        Dim wSheet As Worksheet = New Worksheet
        Dim sData As SheetData = New SheetData

        Dim row1 As Row = New Row
        Dim cell1 As Cell = New Cell
        cell1.DataType = CellValues.InlineString
        cell1.CellReference = "A1"

        Dim iString As InlineString = New InlineString
        Dim txt As Text = New Text
        txt.Text = "hello test"
        iString.Append(txt)
        cell1.Append(iString)
        row1.Append(cell1)

        sData.Append(row1)
        wSheet.Append(sData)
        wSheetPart.Worksheet = wSheet

        sp.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save()
    End Using
```

Comment: The error is related to a problem with the Compatibility Pack, verify you can open other .xlsx files ok. For more info (i'm having a related issue) find my question (+ part solutions) on [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/404902/microsoft-office-compability-pack-the-converter-failed-to-open-the-file-error)